# learning about arrays and was attempting to code a program to find the greatest Integer in an array. Program isn't giving me the solution

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning about arrays and was attempting to code a program to find the greatest Integer in an array. The program isn't giving me the intended solution

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class GreaterInt{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //creating the dimesion for array
        int size = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the values inside the array");
        // Creating an array        
        int [] numbers = new int [size];

        //entering the values in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            numbers [i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        int max  = Integer.MAX_VALUE;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            if (numbers[i] < min){
                min = numbers[i];
            }
            if (numbers[i] > max){
                max = numbers[i];
               
            }
         }
         
         System.out.println("The minimum value in the list of numbers is" + max);
         System.out.println("The maximum value in the list of numbers is" + min);
        }
    }
```

The result I am getting:

```
Enter the size of the array
5
Enter the values inside the array
2
4
2
6
1
The minimum value in the list of numbers is2147483647
The maximum value in the list of numbers is-2147483648
```

Comment: Actually, you have to assign it opposite. `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `max` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to `min`. Also, you are printing `max` for minimum value and `min` for maximum value in SOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialisation is incorrect. You are initialising your min and max variables like

```
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Although it should be the opposite

```
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

In the 1st if block where you are trying to find the minimum number, since min is already equal to Integer.MIN_VALUE, no value of numbers[i] will be lower than that and the if condition will never be true.

```
if (numbers[i] < min) {
    min = numbers[i];
}
```